# How to create jabber account using agsXMPP c#?

Tags: c#, .net, agsxmpp

How to create Jabber account using agsXMPP library in c# .net.?

I have tried to chat between two Jabber users, but for both of them, the JID was already created on Jabber website registration.

But, I want to create JID registration using agsXMPP library in C# application.

Is this possible?

Comment: If they are _Jabbar users_ then its obvious that the JID was already created. What code have you tried already?

Comment: i have tried code for chating and it was success with two jabber ID. but that jabber ID has created by jabber.at web site.    but, i want to create jabber account with my c# app.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the **RegisterAccount** property to true before you connect. The library tries to register the new account and logs in with this account after success (if success).

**OnRegistered** event is raised when the account was created successful.
**OnRegisterError** event is called on errors.

```
XmppClientConnection xmpp = new XmppClientConnection();
// other code
xmpp.Username = "userName";
xmpp.Password = "secretPassword";
xmpp.RegisterAccount = true;

xmpp.OnRegisterError += xmpp_OnRegisterError;
xmpp.OnRegistered += xmpp_OnRegistered;
xmpp.Open();

void xmpp_OnRegistered(object sender)
{
    //handle accordingly
}


void xmpp_OnRegisterError(object sender, agsXMPP.Xml.Dom.Element e)
{
    //handle accordingly
}
```